# Python error No such file or directory

Tags: python

I get the following error: No such file or directory but I'm unsure why. I know it looks easy to explain but I'm unsure what directory its referring to here

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['MY_LIB_PATH'] = '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/projecttest/lib'
subprocess.call(["test_program",image_url],env=env)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    model = get_model(image.get_image_content())
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/projecttest/utilities.py", line 51, in get)model
    env=env
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your `test_program` executable is not found.

Comment: What directory? It looks like the test program isn't there. Is it?

Comment: is `test_program` a python file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the reply. Would that relate to my environ? I get MY_LIB_PATH to point to the folder where they all are

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham no it is not a python file. it points to a lib folder with a .dylib

Comment: Why do you think setting MY_LIB_PATH in the environment would have any effect on how subprocess looks for an executable? Where is `test_program` located? What's your working directory?

Comment: why don't you set the path

Comment: maybe I misunderstood subprocess but it allows an env= to be set in the call() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that a program is found, you need to append to the `PATH` environment variable.

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/projecttest/lib'
subprocess.call(["test_program", image_url], env=env)
```

Or you can call it explicitly;

```
cmd = '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/projecttest/lib/test_program'
subprocess.call([cmd, image_url])
```

Additionally, your `test_program` must be executable.

Note that `subprocess.call` can only execute *programs*. If you want to use a function from a dynamic link library, you'll have to use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: In Windows is `';'` no `':'`.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda From the paths it looks like Spike is running OS X.

Comment: yes I know, I just want to point out that in Windows is different. Other user will read this in the future and there is no tag for an specific OS.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Changed it to use `os.pathsep`. That should work everywhere. Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a random environment variable and expect python to magically read it. Either you:

- Insert the path in `PATH`.
- Use your random environment variable to construct the path, e.g.:

  ```
  subprocess.call([os.path.join(os.environ["MY_LIB_PATH"],
                                "test_program"),
                  img_url])
  ```

Comment: But does call() not allow you to set env=?

Comment: If you set `MY_LIB_PATH`, you can pass `env` to `call` as you say. *Inside* `test_program` you can retrieve `os.environ["MY_LIB_PATH"]`.